# Improve delete performance in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm creating a raw table in snowflake with a field containing date as string in this format '20230511' and I need to delete everyday the last 3 days and insert again, like this:

```
delete from my_table
where date_field = '20230511' or '20230510' or '20230509'

insert into my_table
(select from staging_table)
```

I would prefer to create the table converting this field as date type, but my manager wants to replicate all the data type from the source, so I would like to know if for snowflake makes any difference to use the date field as string or date in terms of performance when using delete operation

I know that snowflake has the concept of micropartions, but I'm not sure if it can interpret the date field range in string well. I would like to be sure, because it's a huge events table, so I'm afraid that in the future the deletion time could take so long.
Obs: unfortunately I cannot use merge because we don't have a unique key

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The datatype of the column will make no (measurable) difference to the speed of the delete

Answer (score 0):

if you are deleting huge amount of rows, you can instead follow below logic -

1. create a new table with non-delete rows.
   `create table tmp_xx as  select * from my_table where date_field Not in ('20230511', '20230510', '20230509')`
2. truncate my_table.
3. Insert data from new tmp_xx table and stage table into my_table.
4. Drop new tmp_xx  table.

OR,

1. create a new table with non-delete rows.
   `create or replace table my_table as  select * from my_table where date_field Not in ('20230511', '20230510', '20230509')`,
2. Insert data from stage table into tmp_xx.

Comment: ooor you use the `insert overwrite into my_table (select * from my_table where <deletion_filter>)` syntax to avoid messing with grants or time-travel settings :)

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but worth an answer: It makes almost no difference if the column is varchar/string, timestamp, or date.

The biggest portion of time spent for most delete queries is the rewriting "surviving" rows from micropartitons that are affected by the delete. I'm not aware of any good solution to speed that up outside of not using `DELETE` and opting for a soft-delete strategy instead. This is independent of any column type.

The table scan on the select portion of the delete is typically the second biggest component. Here, metadata is available for all columns in a micro-partition and min/max-pruning happens on all columns irrespective of their type. All columns have to be loaded during the `DELETE` so there is again no difference in performance for different column types.

The only difference is in terms of kernel performance when computing the actual predicate. Here timestamps are faster. Internally they are just numbers so they are faster to compare than strings. They also benefit from vectorization on modern CPUs. While this difference exists it's normally too small to be of practical relevance.